# How kernel decides what is a suitable module for some hardware device?

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules

Now if some hardware device does not work I have to Google out what kernel options I should turn on to compile a kernel module for this hardware. I hope there is a better way to do it.

Somehow when I boot from live-cd my hardware magically works "of of the box". I guess live-cd contains lot's of modules for various hardware and the kernel somehow knows which module to load and use. Can I do something similar without using live-cd? Say I run lspci, find out all the available information about the hardware and using this information find out what module to compile?

Comment: I've personally found, that frequently hardware doesn't work because it's missing it's firmware that is loaded by the driver, and yes, frequently live distros work out-of-the-box. I usually just copy the of the /lib/firmware directory on the live distro, to my machine, and that fixes a lot of things.

Comment: My question is about how to find suitable module. How come it's a duplicate of a question which asks about major and minor numbers?

Comment: I agree this isn't a duplicate — as I understand it, you want to determine (effectively) the configuration options to use when building a kernel so it supports your hardware, is that correct?

Comment: @stephen-kitt Yes and no. Yes, I do want to be able to configure kernel correctly to support my hardware. But this is not the only goal. I want to understand what is going on and to be able to make sure which steps were definitely successful and where the failure happened. Yesterday I spent 2 hours trying to get sound out of my fresh gentoo. I succeeded, but still do not know if the problem was with wrong kernel options or with pulseaudio package not installed :(